# How to index and partition a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to index and partition a huge but simple table (127 million rows) to speed up querying, using SQL Server Management Studio. It has 99 blocks of monthly data, each month having an integer 1 to 99. I want to partition each month into each partition, and index over the `[ID]` and `[Month]` columns, as I need to query the table doing a comparison of each month to its preceding `[Month]` and each individual's `[ID]`. How do I do this? I have created the partition function

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_Monthly(int)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60
,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70
,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80
,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90
,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99
)
GO
```

And scheme:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_Monthly
AS PARTITION PF_Monthly
ALL TO ( [PRIMARY] );
GO
```

How do I apply this to a table called `[Table]` and its column called `[Month]`? Can I do this after indexing or do I have to re-create the table, then partition and then index? Thanks

Comment: partitioning won't speed up queries in 99% of cases. Correct indexes will. 127 millions rows is relatively small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to index and partition a huge but simple table (127 million rows) to speed up querying,

That's not what partitioning is for.  It might be faster, but partitioning is more of a managability feature, and a feature that allows your workload to be *no slower* as the amount of data grows.  Note *no slower* is not the same as *faster*.

Paritioning is a useful feature for performance, but it's far from a silver bullet. [columnstores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2014) are generally much better at improving query performance on large tables, and can be combined with partitioning.

> How do I apply this to a table called [Table] and its column called [Month]?

The process is documented here: [Move an Existing Index to a Different Filegroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/move-an-existing-index-to-a-different-filegroup?view=sql-server-ver15)

Moving a table to a Partition Scheme is the same as moving it to a different Filegroup.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried moving the index to the partition scheme and it errors. I right click on the index, click Properties, go to Storage, check Partition Scheme, select the PS_Monthly scheme above, and click OK. Then it errors on re-creating, saying: PartitionSchemeParameters need to be non-empty when PartitionScheme has been set.

Comment: Add the table definitions and the the TSQL of the operations.  It's impossible to follow a description of what you did in the GUI.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that, I've found the table definitions but I can't fit it into a comment

Comment: I've just tried creating a columnstore column on [Month] and it says it can't do it on a non-persisted column, I'm working on persisting it now.